# ORA-06550 using a nested table type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create some output based on select items from APEX. 
The case is as follows:

- In APEX you select certain items.
- APEX makes a nested table of those primary keys and call the function to create the output.
- The function generates the output and returns it.

I already found out that I can't use locally defined nested tables in the where clause, but I am now stuck on the following:
My stored type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE  "T_NUMBERS" as table of NUMBER(10,0)
```

The part of the function that gives the ORA-06550 error:

```
DECLARE
c_asked T_NUMBERS;


BEGIN

  c_asked := T_NUMBERS(21);
```

This is just a simple example of what is going wrong.

The error itself:

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 23:
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got <schema_name>.T_NUMBERS
```

Comment: Where is `t_list` defined? `c_asked := t_numbers(21);` compiles, but do you really want a table collection with a single entry?

Comment: Sorry, but that edit was not sufficient to clarify this. Your question now contains two seemingly unrelated types - `t_list` and `t_numbers`, and it lacks the DDL for `t_list`. Please post the *exact* code you're using and the *exact* error message you get.

Comment: I had a few versions. The current version is using T_NUMBERS the older version was using t_list. Now everything has the right name. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: OK, but as I said, that compiles. Are you sure that assignment is line 9? Maybe you can show more of the procedure code, and ake sure the line that throws the error is obvious.

Comment: After a night sleep I found the problem. There was a problem with my schema. I don't know what it was but it seemed to have fixed itself.